# Open Flutter App through externally shared content

Tags: flutter, share

My flutter app has a button that shares content to other apps such as whatsapp, facebook and such. As of now, it only shares texts. I want to make it so that when a user shares content through Whatsapp and those other apps, the receiver can click on the shared link, content or whatever, and (if he has the app) launch the app while navigating to a page related to the shared content.

If I share a specific car model, other users could click on the content in whatsapp, launch the app navigate to the CarPage with the details of the specific model that was shared.

I'm using this package now https://pub.dev/packages/share which allows ACTION_SEND intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)

> If a user opens a Dynamic Link on iOS or Android, they can be taken directly to the linked content in your native app.

**How to create dynamic link?**

> You create a Dynamic Link either by using the Firebase console, using a REST API, iOS or Android Builder API, Flutter API, or by forming a URL by adding Dynamic Link parameters to a URI prefix specific to your app.

```
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
  uriPrefix: 'https://abc123.app.goo.gl',
  link: Uri.parse('https://example.com/'),
  androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
      packageName: 'com.example.android',
      minimumVersion: 125,
  ),
  iosParameters: IosParameters(
      bundleId: 'com.example.ios',
      minimumVersion: '1.0.1',
      appStoreId: '123456789',
  ),
  googleAnalyticsParameters: GoogleAnalyticsParameters(
      campaign: 'example-promo',
      medium: 'social',
      source: 'orkut',
  ),
  itunesConnectAnalyticsParameters: ItunesConnectAnalyticsParameters(
    providerToken: '123456',
    campaignToken: 'example-promo',
  ),
  socialMetaTagParameters:  SocialMetaTagParameters(
    title: 'Example of a Dynamic Link',
    description: 'This link works whether app is installed or not!',
  ),
);

final Uri dynamicUrl = await parameters.buildUrl();
// use this code to sorten the url
final ShortDynamicLink shortenedLink = await DynamicLinkParameters.shortenUrl(
  Uri.parse('https://example.page.link/?link=https://example.com/&apn=com.example.android&ibn=com.example.ios'),
  DynamicLinkParametersOptions(ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.unguessable),
);

final Uri shortUrl = shortenedLink.shortUrl;
```

**Receive dynamic link**

```
 void initDynamicLinks() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;

    if (deepLink != null) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
    }

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
      onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
        final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

        if (deepLink != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
        }
      },
      onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
        print('onLinkError');
        print(e.message);
      }
    );
  }
```